# How do I fix the undefined subroutine main error

Tags: perl, cpan

I am using the CPAN [Unix::Passwd::File](https://metacpan.org/pod/Unix::Passwd::File) module, and when a I use any of its functions, the script throws the error: `Undefined subroutine &main`

For example, for get the max uid:

```
#!/urs/bin/perl
use Unix::Passwd:File;

my $res = get_max_uid();
```

the error is `Undefined subroutine &main::get_max_uid called at scriptname.pl line 4`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quote from the docs:

> This function is not exported by default, but exportable.

Try:

```
my $res = Unix::Passwd:File::get_max_uid();
```

or:

```
use Unix::Passwd:File qw(get_max_uid);
```